# How to listen to a mediaService event using azure functions and event subscriptions

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-eventgrid

I have some encoding jobs using the Azure REST API that I would like to handle on completion. 
I am stil learning the Azure workflow, but it seems that the right way to do it is to create an Azure Function, register it in the event subscription manager and handle the finished jobs in that function.

Right now I have:

- Created a function app in the portal, linked to my subscription and the resource group. I used the example shown here: 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid#javascript-example
- Started the *Create Event Subscription* process in the portal. I selected the Event Grid schema, picked the events I needed to listen to and selected the right resource group and media service account. I t

When I try to create the subscription, I have the following error:

```
Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"Url validation","message":"The attempt to validate the provided endpoint http://myendpoint failed. For more details, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation."}
```

If I then go to my function, I have the following error:

`Function (EventHandler) Error: The binding type(s) 'eventGridTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.`

I've read that I should first install the Azure Event Grid trigger in the portal by creating a new function with that template but it fails with this error : https://mediaevent-handler.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/Functions/extensions/febd7383-0d66-4974-90f0-c266f0c08c2e.json

Am I doing the right process or is there some kind of permission issue?

I am also doing these manipulation as the organization owner.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check to see if the Event Grid Resource Provider is enabled first on your subscription?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/monitor-events-portal-how-to#enable-event-grid-resource-provider

Comment: One more question - which Region is your media account in? Event Grid is not available in Azure Government, China, or Azure Germany at this time - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/azure-clouds-regions#feature-availability-in-azure-clouds

Comment: You raised a great point. I have to use West Europe for our solution. Could a logic app work?

Comment: It seems like germany is not West Europe, and it should be available there. The Microsoft.EventGrid provider is also enabled en our subscription.

Comment: West Europe should be fine.  Logic Apps works very well for Event Grid, but Functions should as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either Functions or Logic Apps to "catch" the Event Grid event from AMS.

I use both quite often. Once you confirm that the RP is enabled in your subscription as noted above, you can create a new Function and choose the "Event Grid Trigger" template. Make sure not to grab the "Event Hub Trigger" which is not the same.

Once it generates, there is a small link next to the "Run" button that says "add Event Grid Subscription". Choose Event Grid Schema, and then for Topic Type choose "Microsoft Azure Media Services", then choose the right subscription, resource group and account name for Media Services.  Then i always uncheck the "Subscribe to all events" checkbox and subscribe to just "Job Finished" or if you want all state changes "Job State Changed".

After that, drop in a little sample code and test it:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static void Run(JObject eventGridEvent, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info(eventGridEvent.ToString(Formatting.Indented));

    var subject = eventGridEvent["subject"].ToString();
    var split = subject.Split('/');
    var transformName = split[1];
    var jobName = split[3];

    log.Info($"Transform = {transformName}");
    log.Info($"Job = {jobName}");
    log.Info($"State = {eventGridEvent["data"]["state"] }");

}
```

UPDATING this answer so that it contains the comments:

It appears the Functions team may have a portal bug. I'll reach out to them.  Check this link out - Following these steps are supposed to fix the issue: github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/

If you follow that and stop/restart the Function app in the portal it should start working.

Another workaround - and a reason i have not run into this myself - is to start with a Logic App - catch the event in the Logic App and then submit the event to the Function as a normal HTTP trigger Function. That is how most of my workflows are built right now and the Logic Apps designer appears to register the event correctly.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do and the issue I have.
When I choose the Event Grid schema, I need to install Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid extension. When I try to install it, I have the following error, like explained in my first post:

Error:

Host Error: [object Object]
Session Id: 935232fbc7ee4372acf2b2a4e5840ff6

Timestamp: 2019-01-24T19:22:07.696Z

We were not able to install the runtime extension. To learn more please view https://mediaevent-handler.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/Functions/extensions/864fbde0-bc96-420e-9cc5-554b7bb88382.json

Comment: I think that the Functions team have a bug in the portal.  Check this link out - 
Following these steps fixed the issue:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions

Comment: If you follow that and stop/restart the Function app in the portal it should start working. 

Another workaround - and a reason i have not run into this myself - is to start with a Logic App - catch the event in the Logic App and then submit the event to the Function as a normal HTTP trigger Function.  That is how most of my workflows are built right now.

Comment: As you suggested, I tried starting with a logic app. I selected my subscription, Microsoft.Media.MediaServices as a resource type, the right media service, selected JobFinishedn JobScheduled and JobErrored and linked that to a basic HTTP request.  I saved and ran it, started a few jobs that went to completion, and got nothing in the logic app. Nothing in the logs as well. Is it related to my issue or did I miss something?

Comment: Very strange.  you are using the V3 API for AMS right? Not the v2 API.

Comment: Can you tell me how you are submitting the job exactly? What code?

Comment: Try submitting a job directly through the v3 Azure Media Explorer tool and see if anything comes back - https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer/releases/tag/v5.0.0.12

Comment: I was using the V2 API to submit the job, because an AMS salesperson told me the V3 wasn't feature complete. Logic apps only listen to the V3 jobs? Is there any other way?

Comment: No sorry.  Event grid only works with the new v3 API.  What feature of the v2 version were you dependent on exactly?  V2 has a web hook notification api that is available in the documentation for that version.